# Como montar uma string com cada item de um array que pode ter 1 valor ou varios valores?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte `array` no momento:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'ketchup' (length=7)
  1 => string 'mustard' (length=7)
  2 => string 'barbecue' (length=8)
```

Eu precisaria montar uma frase assim:

> Você escolheu `ketchup`, `mustard`, `barbecue`.

Porém, o usuario que vai inserir quais molhos ele quer, ele pode por exemplo escolher apenas ketchup, ou apenas mustard, ou ketchup/mustard/barbecue/maionese/pimenta/agridoce, ou seja, o array pode ter 1 item, ou 2 itens, ou 3 itens, ou 4 itens...ou  10 itens, depende do usuario.

Qual logica eu poderia usar pra montar a seguinte estrutura?

Exemplo: Ketchup, Mustard.

> Você escolheu `ketchup`, `mustard`.

Exemplo: Ketchup, Mustard, Barbecue, Maionese, Pimenta, Agridoce.

> Você escolheu `ketchup`, `mustard`, `barbecue`, `pimenta`, `agridoce`.

Já pensei em usar algo assim:

```
echo "Você escolheu $molhos[0], $molhos[1]."
```

Porém como informei, pode ter apenas 1 item o array ou 2 ou 3 ou 4 ou até 10.
Pensei também no `foreach`, porém não consegui chegar a nenhum resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for apenas para formatar use a função `implode()` ela convete um array em string separando os elementos por um delimitador nesse caso a vírgula.

```
$pedido1 = array ('ketchup', 'mustard', 'barbecue', 'pimenta', 'agridoce');
$pedido2 = array ('ketchup', 'mustard');
$pedido3 = array ('ketchup');


echo implode(', ', $pedido1) .'<br>';
echo implode(', ', $pedido2) .'<br>';
echo implode(', ', $pedido3) .'<br>';
```

**[Exemplo - replit](https://repl.it/repls/HeavenlyRepulsiveFlyinglemur)**

Comment: Era isso que eu estava precisando. Eu achava que era algo muito complexo ou uma logica bem longa, mas na verdade era bem mais simples do que eu imaginei. Muito obrigado rray!